# Are there two kinds of .dll files in Windows?

Tags: dll, windows-7

I know that some dll files have to be registered with the regsvr32 command. I tried that on a dll files I got and got an error message saying that "the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found." I heard that to use theis dll file you have to use "ctypes." So what are you supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some DLLs contain COM interfaces. These can be registered, and provide hooks to do so. Others are just normal DLLs, and have entry points with names and/or ordinals. They must be linked appropriately by the script/executable.

Comment: and some DLLs are assemblies (managed code) but your point is still correct.